# SQL Server Always On: How simulate disks in secondary replica which only exist in primary replica

Tags: sql-server, disk, alwayson

I have an Always On system with two replicas: A and B. A is addressed to be mainly the primary replica.

Replica A has 2 local disks dedicated to user databases data and user databases logs: D: and L:.

Replica B has an only disk: E:, and I have created two folders in it for data and logs: E:\Data and E:\Log

Nevertheless, until I know, database folders must be the same in both replicas. In replica A I have D: for user database  data and L: for user database logs. But I have no such disks in replica B.

How can I simulate the necesary disks in B?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hard requirement to have the same file paths on both servers, but it makes your life easier.

In Windows you can create multiple volumes on a single disk.  So on B delete the E volume and add two new volumes on the disk, assigning the driver letters D and L, just like the primary.

Or you could use D:\Data and D:\Logs on both servers by [mounting the L volume as D:\logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive) on the primary, and re-mapping E to D on the secondary.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Create volumes is not an option here because only the last partition can be resized if necessary. With 2 folders in the same disk the whole space can be used.

Comment: See updated answer.